# Toshiba Tecra A10 - WiFi not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 17.04

I have a recycled "Toshiba Tecra A10", I have done a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.04. Everything is perfectly working except Wi-Fi, which is causing me an headache.

After the installation, the "Enable Wi-Fi" was untoggled and the widget is correctly saying that the Wi-Fi is disabled. So I tried to enable it via widget, but still the Wi-Fi is disabled.

I tried to use the keyboard combination for enabling the Wi-Fi card, the `rfkill` is not encouraging from:

```
root@sulaco:~# rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: Toshiba WWAN: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

to:

```
root@sulaco:~# rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: Toshiba WWAN: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Still no luck if I try to unblock all:

```
root@sulaco:~# rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: Toshiba WWAN: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Here the card infos:

```
root@sulaco:~# lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 03
       serial: 00:1c:7e:29:9b:b6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=1.8-8 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:ffcc0000-ffcdffff memory:ffcfe000-ffcfefff ioport:cf80(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: WiFi Link 5100
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: de:d5:02:78:77:3a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-19-generic firmware=8.83.5.1 build 33692 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:ff900000-ff901fff
```

I have no clue, any help is very welcome, thanks!

Comment: I've seen a lot of people having problems when upgrading from Ubuntu 16.xx to Ubuntu 17.04. I suggest burning a LiveCD/LiveUSB with Ubuntu 16.04 and check if the problem still exists. If the same problem exists on 16.04, you should wait for someone to help you.

Comment: Yup, I installed a 16.04 before trying the 17.04, same problem.

Comment: Since it's marked as Hard-Blocked, you may have pressed a button that toggles the specific device on/off. My Laptop has a Flight-Mode button that disables bluetooth and networking. Do you have a flight-mode button?

Comment: No button, sadly.

Comment: I am ashamed that I finally found a switch on the left side of the notebook that was disabling the wireless...
Now it is working nicely!

Comment: You can mark my post as an "answer" so people know this question is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answered on comments*

Since it's marked as **Hard-Blocked**, you may have pressed a button that toggles the specific device **on/off**. My Laptop has a Flight-Mode button that disables bluetooth and networking. Do you have a **Flight-Mode** button?